New variable names from series of checkbox answers not working
I am relatively new to SAS and have no background in programming at all, but I have recently encountered a problem that even my PhD supervisors are stumped by. I conduced a survey on dairy cow management last year and many of the questions were checkboxes. The data came out to be a series of columns with either a number or a zero in each column; corresponding to a checked or unchecked answer for that particular aspect of the question. For example, this particularly problematic checkbox question pertains to pre-milking practices on dairy farms with 11 possible answers. I now want to make a new column (PREMILK) with all applicable checkbox answers in one column (i.e. any combination of ten PreMilk_X answers are possible; one answer (PreMilk_None) pertains to doing nothing so all other columns should be '0'), but it just won't work.
Based on what I've read, I should not be overwhelming SAS with the amount of code. If I start with the "if everything equals 0 bar this one thing, call it 'x'", it refuses to compute any of the possible combinations. If I start with the combinations, it only names them with two characters (i.e. if a '4' and a '6' and a '7' are checked, I try to rename it '467' but only '46' is present in the new column). I need this column for univariate anaylsis for a mixed model using PROC MIXED.
I am not getting any errors; only the R matrix omitting observations warning. I'll insert my code below. It looks horrendous, but it's basically specifying that if x equals a check and y does not, the PREMILK column should distinguish this from a situation where x equals a check and y also equals a check.
Any help is appreciated!
/* PREMILK MONSTER */
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM0; SET CSVMOSURVEYM;
    IF PreMilk_None='1' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='0';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='2';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='3';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='4';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='5';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='6';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='8' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='7';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='9' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='8';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='9';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='10'; run;

/DRYWIPE/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM1; SET CSVMOSURVEYM;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='12';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='124';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1245';    

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='12459';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='124510';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1246';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='12469';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='124610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1249';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='12410';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='125'; 

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1256';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1259';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='12510';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='12569';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='125610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='126';     

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1269';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='12610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='129';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='1210';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='13';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='134';     

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='136';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1369';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='13610';  

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='139';    

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='1310';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='14';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='146';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='1469';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='14610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='149';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='1410';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='15';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='159';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='1510';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='16';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='169';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='1610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='19';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='2' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='110'; RUN;

/HOSE/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM2; SET CSVMOSURVEYM1;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='24';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='246';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='2469';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='24610';
    
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='249';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='2410';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='25';  
    
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='259';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='26';      

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='2610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='29';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='3' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='210'; run;

/PREDIP/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM3; SET CSVMOSURVEYM2;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='34';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='36';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='3610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='8' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='37';  

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='8' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='3710';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='39';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='4' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='310'; run;

/PRESPRAY/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM4; SET CSVMOSURVEYM3;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='45';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='46';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='469';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='4610';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='8' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='47';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='49';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='5' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='410'; run;

/INDWASH/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM5; SET CSVMOSURVEYM4;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='6' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='59';

/COMMWASH/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM6; SET CSVMOSURVEYM5;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='10' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='69';

    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='7' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='0' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='610'; run;

/WASHCUP/
DATA CSVMOSURVEYM7; SET CSVMOSURVEYM6;
    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='8' AND PreMilk_Brush='9' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='0' THEN PREMILK='78';  


    IF PreMilk_None='0' AND PreMilk_DryWipe='0' AND PreMilk_Hose='0' AND PreMilk_PreDip='0' AND PreMilk_PreSpray='0' AND PreMilk_IndClothWash ='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothWash='0' AND PreMilk_PreWashCup='8' AND PreMilk_Brush='0' AND  PreMilk_IndClothDry='0' AND PreMilk_CommClothDry='11' THEN PREMILK='710'; run;


You need to describe your actual data much better.  For example why are you sometimes looking for '1' and other times looking for '2' or '3'? Posting a simple example data step to create such a file is the best way.  You probably only need to show 3 of 4 observations and 3 or 4 or the "checkbox" variables to demonstrate.  Show what result you want for example input.

The reason you get 46 instead of 467 is because you did not DEFINE the variable long enough to store more than 2 bytes.
If you do not define the length of a character variable then SAS will guess what length you wanted based on just the information available when you first use it in your code.  So if you have something like:
if a=1 then b='46';
else b='467';

It will define B to have length $2 since the first place you use it you assigned it a value that was only 2 bytes long.
To fix that just define the variable before using it.
length b $3 ;
if a=1 then b='46';
else b='467';


Assuming what you want to do is the correct thing to do (I have reservations, but I'll set those aside for now), this is pretty straightforward and done all the time in survey research.
data want;
  set have;
  final_premilk = cats(of premilk_:);
run;

That's the simple version - just concatenate them all together.  Now, you have a small issue where this has extra zeros, and your values also contain '10'; this isn't an issue "per se" insofar as you are still getting unique results here (and so you can probably use the resulting variable), but it's not precisely what you're asking for, and since you have '10' you can't just compress the 0. This also relies on them being in the right order to some extent, though since you have different values it's probably not an issue.
Here is how I would handle it typically; importantly, we like to differentiate between 'answered the question' and 'did not answer the question', hence differentiating '0' from ' '.
data want;
  set have;
  array premilk premilk_:;  *or if the order could be wrong and matters, specify it explicitly here;
  length final_premilk $256; *or whatever the max length is;
  final_premilk = ' ';
  do _i = 1 to dim(premilk);
    if premilk[_i] > '0' then final_premilk = cats(final_premilk,premilk[_i]);
  end;
  if cats(of premilk[*]) ne ' ' then final_premilk='0'; *if the question was answered but all boxes are unchecked (0) as opposed to the question was not answered (so all boxes are empty (missing) - depending on survey logic this differentiation may or may not be possible;
run;

Here we just iterate through an array and check if it has a value, if so we append it.
You also could treat '10' like 'A', '11' like 'B', etc.; you also could treat it like a 1/0 flag (so '11000010110' means 1,2,7,9,10 were checked).  The latter is what we prefer where I work.
All this aside though, for most analysis the separate variable flag is actually better - but of course it depends on exactly what you're doing.

To me it looks like the pattern is that each variable can have a value of either '0' or its position in the list.  So the first variable can be '0' or '1'.  Then second and be '0' or '2'. etc.
If the number of variables is small (less than 15) then you could create a binary number that summarizes the result.
So something like this:
data want ;
  set have;
  array _premilk premilk_: ;
  premilk=0;
  do i=1 to dim(_premilk);
    if _premilk[i]^='0' then premilk+2**(i-1);
  end;
  drop i;
run;

Let's make an example and try it.
data have ;
  input id (premilk_none premilk_other premilk_CommClothDry) (:$2.) ;
cards;
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
2 0 2 0
3 1 2 0
4 0 0 3
5 1 0 3
6 0 2 3
7 1 2 3
;

Result:

Otherwise you could make a character variable.  Just make sure to define it long enough for all possible combinations.
data want ;
  set have;
  array _premilk premilk_: ;
  length premilk $60 ;
  do i=1 to dim(_premilk);
    if _premilk[i]^='0' then premilk=catx(',',premilk,substr(vname(_premilk[i]),9));
  end;
  drop i;
run;

Result:

